# In angular how to redirect without history in $state

Tags: angularjs

How do i do this in $state

```
$location.path('/someNewPath').replace();
```

I basically want to redirect without the url showing up in history

Comment: could you try `$state.go('stateName', {notify: false})`

Answer (score 3):

Straight from [the documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go)

> location - {boolean=true|string=} - If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. **If string, must be "replace", which will update url and also replace last history record.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: To be clear, you need to `$state.go('stateName', {}, {location: 'replace'})`.